# Check if mail was successfully sent in VB.NET with SMTPClient

Tags: vb.net, smtp, smtpclient

I'm trying to create an application that sends an email to an smtp-server.

The server is not set fixed, but will be looked up according to the domainpart of the email-address where the email should be sent to.

Example:

Email To: test@stackoverflow.com

Domain-Part: stackoverflow.com

Result of a MX-Record Lookup (commandline "nslookup -type=mx stackoverflow.com":

> stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 30, mail exchanger = stackoverflow.com.s9b1.psmtp.com
>   stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 40, mail exchanger = stackoverflow.com.s9b2.psmtp.com
>   stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 10, mail exchanger = stackoverflow.com.s9a1.psmtp.com
>   stackoverflow.com       MX preference = 20, mail exchanger = stackoverflow.com.s9a2.psmtp.com

It would be quite useful, to know if the message was accepted by the mailserver and the message was successfully sent.

What I am able so far is, that I can get the SMTP-Server error code (if there was an error (StatusCode 5xx) by using the System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient Object and its SendAsync Function. There, if there was an error, I get an Exception-Object in the Callback-Event of the SMTPClient

I'm well aware that not every mailserver will tell me if the mailaccount truly exists and then reject my mail with an errorcode but instead just accept the message and then delete it. Therefore I would be grateful for another Method to check if the mail was sent (note: not read, that would be the read confirmation)

The final purpose would be:
Try to send an email to a recipient using it's domains mailserver and if it fails, proceed according to the errorcode (user does not exist -> abort / mailserver did not respond -> use another mailserver if available).

Thanks in advance (and sorry for typos :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you are looking for does not exist. Email jumps through so many hops that there is no definition of what "sent" actually means. For instance, your example of stackoverflow actually points to Postini's email servers. Postini probably passes the email around from gateways to AV's and routers. From there they either pool email or pass them on to another email server.

With email, the closest definition of "sent" is "at least I didn't get an error".

Also, a minor thing, but when using nslookup remember to add a trailing period to the domain, otherwise the domain search list is used. Generally not a big deal but every once in a while it might trip you up.

```
nslookup -type=mx stackoverflow.com.
```

Comment: Yes, its very frustrating from a programmers standpoint but imagine what a spammer could do with this information. They could (and do) create a dictionary of every possible combination of letters and numbers and try them at every possible SMTP server. The ones that are "sent" are valid and the rest are invalid. Now they've got a pure list of valid email addresses and every SMTP admin out there is crying because they're machines are being hit with millions of SMTP request.

Comment: if I add a trailing period to the domain, what is exactly the difference compared to without and why could it cause problems if looked a domainname up without one?

Comment: It almost never matters actually, but without the trailing period you are actually saying "see if this entry exists as a subdomain of XYZ and if that fails then check if its a valid domain on its own". If your machine is part of a corporate network with a domain of "company.local" then doing an nslookup on "example.com" actually searches "examples.com.company.local" first. The odds of this actually resolving are very small so it almost never matters but I seen an occasional issue creep up from some weirdly configured DNS servers.